# Where to place a "Add Car" button

Tags: mobile, buttons, placement

I am really trying to make it simple and elegant but I can't decide where to place this button where a user can add there car to there profile.
I attached a screenshot of my mobile app, any answer will be very helpful.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Subtle aligment tweaks and a plus button top right maybe?]

My humble thoughts. Align the left side better and add a sort of '+' sign in the top right. Maybe make it subtle though so as to not distract the eye too much?

Comment: Nice catch! Yeah this still mocked out in code. I appreciate this!

Comment: Pleasure, just my opinion but hope it helped. Good luck with the project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your Image, I would recommend placing the Add car button with a small car icon with a + next to it below the "cars" text counter, grouping things together like this makes the user more likely to understand what it is they are doing, either that or under the Gear icon and a clear text option that says "add car" or "add my car".
From the above answer I would use either this with the car icon or my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From the above answer I would use either this with the car icon or my suggestion.t should be positioned on the black background so it is easily spottable. Also, use "+" icon

Comment: If you can please reference the poster or quote part of the answer just in case the placement of answers changes.